# Bootstrap 4 mobile flexbox too wide

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So my problem is that my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="w-100 col-auto col-lg-5 w-auto p-3 p-lg-5 m-4 rounded-sm bg-dark text-white shadow-lg">
         <h3>This is a very very very long Text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

results in this:
[Too long Text in Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7zbx.png)

The column is too wide for my Mobile (or in this case Firefox), i think it is because of the Margin and Padding.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: m-4 is the problem... & w-100 for what 100% or 100px

Comment: don't use margin in col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add flex-shrink-1 and flex-grow-1. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

> Best way is, don't try to apply your custom or any other classes to flex layout or the bootstrap's dedicated classes.
>
> don't use margin in col bcz they have a predifined width. width auto take the width till it's content.

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-5 p-lg-5">
    <div class="w-auto p-3 m-4 rounded-sm bg-dark text-white shadow-lg">
         <h3>This is a very very very long Text</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```